# How To print picture from android using Bluetooth printer device

Tags: java, android, printing, bitmap, bluetooth

I'm working on android Bluetooth devices, I want to create an application that print something's from android phone via a Bluetooth printer. I have done to code and test printing of text, but I can't find the right way to print pictures such us logo for example.... What I have done is to convert a bitmap to ByteArrayOutputStream, but I don't have any idea how to complete ... 
I use the  [Rego MPTII 4D Bluetooth Printer](http://www.lelong.com.my/rego-mptii-4d-bluetooth-printer-jdsystems-136628604-2014-09-Sale-P.htm) which has SDK for android:

My code to convert Bitmap to ByteArrayOutputStream is here:

```
private int mWidth;//  
private int mHeight;//  
private String mStatus;//
private BitSet dots;//
private ByteArrayOutputStream mService;//

public void print_image()
    {
        MainActivity m = new MainActivity();

    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(m.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    //ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    //byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();


    //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
    convertBitmap(bmp);

    try {
        mService.write(PrinterCommands.SET_LINE_SPACING_24);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < bmp.getHeight()) {
        try {
            mService.write(PrinterCommands.SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.getWidth(); ++x) {

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {

                byte slice = 0;
                for (int b = 0; b < 8; ++b) {
                    int y = (((offset / 8) + k) * 8) + b;
                    int i = (y * bmp.getWidth()) + x;
                    boolean v = false;
                    if (i < dots.length()) {
                        v = dots.get(i);
                    }
                    slice |= (byte) ((v ? 1 : 0) << (7 - b));
                }
                mService.write(slice);
            }
        }
        offset += 24;
        try {
            mService.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            mService.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            mService.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            mService.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            mService.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            mService.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            mService.write(PrinterCommands.SET_LINE_SPACING_30);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public String convertBitmap(Bitmap inputBitmap) {

     mWidth = inputBitmap.getWidth();
     mHeight = inputBitmap.getHeight();

    convertArgbToGrayscale(inputBitmap, mWidth, mHeight);
     mStatus = "ok";
    return mStatus;
}

private void convertArgbToGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal, int width,
        int height) {
    int pixel;
    int k = 0;
    int B = 0, G = 0, R = 0;
     dots = new BitSet();


        for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
                // get one pixel color
                pixel = bmpOriginal.getPixel(y, x);

                // retrieve color of all channels
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                G = Color.green(pixel);
                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                // take conversion up to one single value by calculating
                // pixel intensity.
                R = G = B = (int) (0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B);
                // set bit into bitset, by calculating the pixel's luma
                if (R < 55) {                       
                    dots.set(k);//this is the bitset that i'm printing
                }
                k++;

            }


        }



}
```

And my PrinterCommands.java:

```
public class PrinterCommands {
public static final byte[] INIT = {27, 64};
public static byte[] FEED_LINE = {10};

public static byte[] SELECT_FONT_A = {27, 33, 0};

public static byte[] SET_BAR_CODE_HEIGHT = {29, 104, 100};
public static byte[] PRINT_BAR_CODE_1 = {29, 107, 2};
public static byte[] SEND_NULL_BYTE = {0x00};

public static byte[] SELECT_PRINT_SHEET = {0x1B, 0x63, 0x30, 0x02};
public static byte[] FEED_PAPER_AND_CUT = {0x1D, 0x56, 66, 0x00};

public static byte[] SELECT_CYRILLIC_CHARACTER_CODE_TABLE = {0x1B, 0x74, 0x11};

//public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, -128, 0};
public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, (byte) 255, 3};
public static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACING_24 = {0x1B, 0x33, 24};
public static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACING_30 = {0x1B, 0x33, 30};

public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_PRINTER_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x01};
public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_OFFLINE_PRINTER_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x02};
public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_ERROR_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x03};
public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_ROLL_PAPER_SENSOR_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x04};
}
```

Let us suppose that the code above works successfully, so how we will complete ?

I Googled a lot but there isn't any solutions on the internet ... can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my English isn't good.